# SSH portforward and direct SSH to remote box

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

There are 2 servers - server1, server2. To access app port on server2, I go via port forwarding.

**ssh myuser@server1 -L 7777:server2:9999**

So, now I simply direct my browser & point it to 7777 and it connects me to my app port on server2.

But when I do a ssh to server2 directly, then it fails.

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @
>   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
>
> IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be
>   eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also
>   possible that the RSA host key has just been changed. The fingerprint
>   for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
>   `33:0d:01:d3:09:33:55:91:eb:19:90:70:51:cb:cd:c2`. Please contact your
>   system administrator. Add correct host key in `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`
>   to get rid of this message. Offending key in `/root/.ssh/known_hosts:7`
>   RSA host key for server2 has changed and you have requested strict
>   checking. Host key verification failed.

From the error, it appears that my key is not present in the authorized key list at the server [ correct? ]. But then I am able to do port forward to app port on server2.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a http://www.serverfault.com question, but: It seems like server 2's SSH certificate has changed since the last time you tried to access it, so your client is raising alarms because the certificate's different from the one that it knows about.

Comment: How come I am able to ssh port fwd into server2's app port? It makes me think that ssh port fwd & direct ssh access to box are 2 independent accesses?

Comment: In the tunneling scenario, you establish an SSH connection to server 1, which then forwards the port 9999 from server 2 via a secure connection. No SSH connection is made to server 2 from server 1 in this situation. Meanwhile, when you do `ssh server2` from your own machine, your client looks in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for the key signature that it gets from the remote server, and determines if they match (or if it even exists). In your case, it got a key for server 2, but your `known_hosts` file has a different key.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thanx..